# Rails Link_to is linking to undesired view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-routing, link-to

My link_to in my view is going to a completely different "show.html.erb" than I'd like it to.  I'm basically trying to understand why the "link_to @exhibit is linking to an "Investigation" profile.  I think it may have to do with my routes file or the fact that its a "belong to" relationship...but can't seem to get it workin...what should that link_to be?

UPDATE: (AS PER BROIS QUESTION)
The missing misbehaving link_to is in the <%= link_to @exhibit do %> in show.html.erb

MY EXHIBIT.RB (MODEL)

```
class Exhibit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :investigation_id, :name, :user_id, :media, :media_html
  belongs_to :investigation

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :content, presence: true
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }

  auto_html_for :media do
  html_escape
  image
  youtube(:width => 400, :height => 250)
  link :target => "_blank", :rel => "nofollow"
  simple_format
end
```

MY EXHIBIT CONTROLLER:

```
class ExhibitsController < ApplicationController
include AutoHtml

def new
@exhibit = Exhibit.new
end

def show
@exhibit = Exhibit.find(params[:id])
end

def index
@exhibits = Exhibit.paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def create
  @investigation = Investigation.find(params[:investigation_id])
  @exhibit = @investigation.exhibits.create(params[:exhibit])
  if @exhibit.save
  flash[:success] = "You've successfully added etc etc..."
  redirect_to investigation_path(@investigation)
  else
  render 'new'
  end
end

end
```

MY ROUTES.RB

```
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

resources :investigations do
resources :players
end

resources :investigations do
resources :exhibits
end
```

LASTLY MY SHOW.HTML.ERB (INVESTIGATION PROFILE)

```
<% @investigation.exhibits.each do |exhibit| %>
  <div class="row-fluid services_circles">
    <%= link_to @exhibit do %>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <%= exhibit.media_html %>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading"><%= exhibit.name %></h4>
        <p><%= exhibit.content %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

ADDED THE INVESTIGATIONS CONTROLLER

```
class InvestigationsController < ApplicationController


def new
  @investigation = Investigation.new
end

def show
   @investigation = Investigation.find(params[:id])
end

def index
  @investigations = Investigation.paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def create
  @investigation = Investigation.new(params[:investigation])
  if @investigation.save
    flash[:success] = "You've successfully created..."
    redirect_to @investigation
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

end
```

ADDED THE INVESTIGATION MODEL

```
class Investigation < ActiveRecord::Base
  # belongs_to :user

  has_many :players, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :exhibits, dependent: :destroy


  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
end
```

I appreciate the help...if i need to post any more info just let me know

Comment: You are using @investigation variable, but it is not set inside your show action. Is it being set somewhere inside the view or is it the 'create' view?

Comment: Please clarify which view the supposedly misbehaving link exists in show the code for that view. You have "Investigation profile" in parentheses after `show.html`.erb`, but it's not clear what that means. Do you have a `InvestigationProfile` class that you haven't shared?

Comment: @BroiSatse I think I see...@investigation is set inside my Investigations Model/Controller...(all exhibits belong_to investigations).

Comment: BroiSatse, So the show.html.erb shown is for the Investigations Profile ( I have an investigations model and controller but didn't think i'd need to post that...will do now.)  I want this link_to @exhibit to link to an exhibit show.html.erb

Comment: Just updated with investigation model and controller...any ideas?  thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN YOUR : app/contorollers/exhibits_controller.rb

```
def show
@investigation = Investigation.find(params[:investigation_id])
@exhibit = Exhibit.find(params[:id])
end
```

IN YOUR : app/views/exhibits/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to investigation_exhibit_path(@investigation, @exhibit) do %>
```

Maybe, I think.

Comment: When I do that it gives me the following error on the investigation profile (show.html.erb) "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"exhibits", :investigation_id=>"

Comment: I think you're on the money about the controller...but the link_to in the view seems to still be off.  appreciate the help, Heungju

Comment: Got it...it just needed to be (@investigation, exhibit).  thanks a bunch.